# method timeout instead of waiting

Tags: breeze, savechanges

It would appear that the savechanges method on breeze waits indefinitely when calling to or waiting for the server. Is there a way of getting it to time out? I am calling save change with *allowConcurrentSaves*: false. This now causes users who somehow do not get a response from the server to simply hang in limbo indefinitely say for example with a dropped internet connection.

I do not want to re-call the method with *allowConcurrentSaves* to false fearing that I might duplicate the data.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Update 16 May 2014

You can set HTTP-level timeout and cancellation with the AJAX Adapter's `requestInterceptor` as of v.1.4.12. See the documentation, ["Controlling AJAX calls"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax).

I'd still be reluctant to use this feature on save as you have no chance of knowing what whether the server persisted the data or not. Of course if your client hangs or crashes you don't know anyway. It's up to you.

## Original Answer

Actually, there is a ready-made solution from [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#readme). It's called `timeout` and it's mentioned in the  [API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) with a simplified example of its implementation and use in the [readme.md](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#readme).

I know you asked about Save but your question is pertinent for promises in general. Here is a query example adapted from the queryTests.js in [our DocCode Sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/doccode)

```
var timeoutMs = 10000; // 10 second timeout
var em = newEm();      // creates a new EntityManager

var query = new EntityQuery().from("Customers").using(em); 

Q.timeout(query.execute, timeoutMs)
    .then(queryFinishedBeforeTimeout)
    .fail(queryFailedOrTimedout);

function queryFailedOrTimedout(error) {
    var expect = /timed out/i;
    var emsg = error.message;
    if (expect.test(emsg)) {
        log("Query timed out w/ message '{0}' " + expectTimeoutMsg)
            .format(emsg));
        // do something
    } else {
        handleFail(error);
    }
}
```

Note: I just added this test so you'd have to get if from github or wait for a Breeze release after 1.2.5.

## Oops ... maybe not

I gave what I think is a great answer for **query**. It may not be the right answer for **save**.

The problem with save is that you do not know on the client if the save succeeded until the server responds. Things could go wrong anywhere along the way. The server might not have heard the request to save. The server may have failed during save. The server may have saved the data but the response never made it back to the client.

Changing the value of `allowConcurrentSaves` won't get you out of this bind. Neither will having a save timeout.

In fact, **adding a timeout to the save is probably deceiving**. It is even possible for the save response to arrive after your custom timeout ... in which case Breeze will have tried to update your EntityManager ... and you won't know if Breeze succeeded or failed!

What if we added a Breeze save timeout. What should it do? What if breeze said the save had timedout ... and Breeze ignored a belated response from the server? Then imagine that the save succeeded on the server - it just took "too long" for it to respond to the client. Now you've got a client whose state is unexpectedly out of sync with the server. This is not good.

So I think you want a different solution to this very real problem. It's a user experience problem really. You can indicate to the user that you think the save is still in progress and then set your own timer. If the save isn't done when your timer expires, you can query the server to see if the data have been saved or if there is a connection ... or something along these lines.  I can't think of a better way right now honestly.

*Note that I'm assuming you need to know that the server succeeded. If you avoid store-generated IDs and always assume saves succeed unless the server tells you otherwise ... well that's a completely different paradigm and programming model that we could talk about someday (see [meteorjs](http://meteor.com/))*.

The net of all of this: I'm pretty darned sure that **a save timeout is NOT what you want**.

Still useful on a query though :)

Answer (score 0):

Great question, and I wish I had a good answer. But it is definitely worth looking into.  Could you please add this as a feature request to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take these requests very seriously in determining our priorities for Breeze development.